# Selenium Webdriver click and send keys etc dont work on Google Chrome Version 78.0.3904.87

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Google chrome automatically updated to Version 78.0.3904.87 yesterday and i now seem to have a problem with Selenium Webdriver.

When i run my tests in Visual Studio, the click events seem to occur but the expected result on screen does not happen e.g. clicking a link passes through the code (link.Click) successfully with no failure but the link does not get clicked on screen.

When i run the same test in Debug mode and Step Into each section of code it works fine, its as if selenium is running too fast for the browser (i have an implicit wait built in but its irrelevant, the element is there its just not clicking properly). I'm also finding things like sendKeys does not populate the field though it passes through the code successfully, again fine when stepping into it in Debug mode.

I've tried updating my Chromedriver to the version for V78 but this has made no difference

Similar problem here but my issue is not restricted to pdfs only
[Chromedriver 78 cant find element in pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58589425/possible-issue-with-chromedriver-78-selenium-can-not-find-web-element-of-pdf-op)

Answer (score 3):

My team is running into the same issue. The issue seems to be the time between our WebDriverWaits and our Clicks -- the waits seem to be passing through instantaneously in cases they should not and then any Click element call (or action) hovers over what we want to click on but doesn't actually click.

Comment: as a temporary workaround i have uninstalled Chrome, downloaded the previous version and installed it, and followed the online instructions to prevent Chrome automatically updating itself. Everything works fine again. Chrome auto update is an absolute joke.

Comment: Our temporary workaround is to add a 500ms sleep after loading a new page, not ideal :( It's a little easier for us to do that than change every machine we test on/with to use older chrome...

Comment: Thanks - does that mean you have had to add multiple sleeps within your framework whenever an action does a page load?
Or some sort of abstract method that does the sleep? (if so how do you call it from the various place that cause a page load?).

Comment: We have a call on our base page that we use on all the other pages that waits until the page finishes loading in general--it's basically just this
`void WaitOnPageLoad()
{
 var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
 wait.Until(By.ClassName("footer"));
 Thread.Sleep(500);
}`

Answer (score 1):

I finally got to the bottom of this with our setup and it turned out to be the --enable-automation flag that seemed to be causing page flickering on page load.
After adding excludeSwitches: ['enable-automation'] to my config it has resolved the issue.